# Link not working after render partial js

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

So what I want is to re-render a table after updating an event.

I do it like this:

```
## My Controller:

respond_to do |format|
  if schedule_child.save
     sql = "schedules.doctor_id = ? AND schedules.location_id = ? AND schedule_children.start_time >= ? AND schedule_children.start_time <= ?"
     @schedules = ScheduleChild.joins(:schedule).where(sql, current_doctor.id, session[:location_id], Time.now, Time.now + 7.days).order(start_time: :asc).page(params[:page]).per(7)
     format.js {render :layout => false}
  end
end
```

My js.erb:

```
$('#schedules').html( "<%= escape_javascript( render "schedules" ) %>" );
```

My view:

```
%a.status_link.btn.btn-success.btn-sm{"data-href" => set_schedule_status_path(location_id: session[:location_id] ,id: schedule.id), :style => "#{schedule.is_away ? 'display: none' : '' }", :id => "#{schedule.id}", :remote => "true"}
          %i.fa.fa-check-square-o 
          %span Available
```

The table was successfully rendered but I cannot click the link in my view. What did I do wrong? Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of `"data-href"` as the link instead of `"href"` requires additional javascript to make the link available. Probably you have that javascript in place and are calling it on `document.ready` and apply your javascript logic on every link with the data property "data-href".

If this is the case you have four options (just guesses as I don't know what logic for data-href you are using):

- Use `href` instead of `data-href`
- Call the logic that enables the link in your js.erb (after you replaced the table)
- Call the logic that enables the link on `document.ready` and `ajaxStop`
- Define the logic on a parent node that exists always like `$('body').on('click', 'a[data-href]', ...`

Comment: If I use `href` I get this error `ActionController::UnknownFormat`. What makes them different?

Comment: data-href works via javascript onclick while href is a native link. `ActionController::UnknownFormat` means that you are requesting a response format you do not handle in the given path. `set_schedule_status_path(location_id: session[:location_id] ,id: schedule.id, format: :js)` would be for js format.

Comment: Based on your answer, I manage to make it works by redefining `$("a.status_link").click(function()` in my js.erb (I go to option 2). Also option 4 works too. I wonder which one is the best approach? Both option 2 and 4 works perfectly (I haven't tried option 3), but option 2 makes my function duplicate(?)